# Quick subtraction without borrow

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

Is there a quick way in hardware or software to subtract without borrow? ie. `9 - 11 = 98`
I would like to implement this in C++, but inline assembly is an option.

Comment: Can you show why the result is 8?

Comment: There is no way to subtract using two's complement without taking 1 from 0 (borrowing).

Comment: @nhahtdh I believe it works by subtracting each column, and if that results in a negative, add 10 to the result of that column subtraction.

Comment: @KendrickLamar: XOR operation will do "subtraction" (or "addition"), ignoring carry and borrow.

Comment: @chewsocks: 0 - 1 is -1, add 10 will be 9, so won't your result be 98 instead of 8?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes you are right, I will fix the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh - XOR might be more efficient. I was thinking about iterating and updating the bits for carry op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `abs((X % 10) - (Y % 10))`

Comment: or (10 + X % 10 - Y % 10) % 10.

Comment: Yes those do work! Is there a big difference between `abs` and an extra `%`?